# Graph Theory Coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

There are some earthlings and 15 martians in a space shuttle. Each earth- ling shook hands with exactly 6 martians, and each martian shook hands with exactly 8 earthlings. How many earthlings are there in the shuttle?

Tried a picture, but it got messy. There should be a formula to make this way easy, but I can't find it.

Comment: Did you try it for smaller numbers and try to work out the formula from there?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I tried a smaller scale if it would mess up the coloring or not. But I will try.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of handshakes done by all the earthlings = total number of handshakes done by all the martians.
The total number of handshakes done by the martians = $8\times15$
Therefore if the total number of earthlings is $x$, then $6\times x=8\times 15$. That is, there were $x=20$ earthlings.

Comment: Can you change this to a solution done by coloring though?

Comment: Can you draw a color graph or an example similar to it by using coloring?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if each earthling shook hands with $6$ martians, and each martian shook hands with $8$ earthlings, then the ratio of martians to earthlings must be $6/8 = 3/4$, so there must be $\frac 4 3 \cdot 15 = 20$ earthlings.

Comment: Can you change this to a solution done by coloring though?